# Array javascript - saber quantidade de agencias quem tenho

Tags: array, for

> Eu precisava saber a quantidade de agencias que tenho no meu arquivo json e seus respectivos números, no caso sei que são 4, mas o retorno que esta sendo dado é um array das 120 contas apenas, e eu gostaria de um array com as 4 agencias, se alguém puder ajudar.

```
const ordenaAgencia=async()=>{
  const data = await getData();
  return await data.sort((item1, item2)=>item1.agencia-item2.agencia)  
};

const maiorCadaAgencia=(dados)=>{
  const agencias = [];
  for(var i=0; i<dados.length; i++){
    if(i == 0){
      if(dados[i] != dados[i+1]){
        agencias.push(dados[i].agencia)
      }
    } else if(dados[i] != dados[i-1]){
     agencias.push(dados[i].agencia)
    }
  }
  console.info(agencias)
}

ordenaAgencia().then(dados=>{
  maiorCadaAgencia(dados)
});
```

Comment: Esquece galera, acho q acabei de encontra a cagada q eu fiz, esqueci de comparar as agencias e estava comparando apenas os dados

Comment: Você pode postar a resposta a sua pergunta, assim pode ajuda outros que passaram pelo mesmo problema.

Answer (score 0):

Olá!

Seria interessante você fazer uma busca no array de agencias para saber se aquela agência já foi lançada. Eu não testei, mas você poderia ver se funciona:

```js
const maiorCadaAgencia=(dados)=>{
  const agencias = [];
  for(var i=0; i<dados.length; i++){
    if(agencias.findIndex(dados[i].agencia) == -1) // Procura o número da agência
    {
      // Se não for encontrado, retorna -1. Assim você pode lançar essa agência no array.
      agencias.push(dados[i].agencia)
    }
    // Não há implementação de ELSE, pois se o resultado for 0 ou maior, é porque você
    // já lançou aquela agência no array

    
  }
  console.info(agencias);
}
```

Sucesso! Responda se deu certo...